# MySQL: How to Show previous day data with next day data in same row

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to show the previous day record of NameofState in the new column, next to TCCIN

[image: Table structure]

For example

[image]

Name of State can be increase or decrease I have tried on below query but it's not working properly do I need to follow different approach

```
       CASE 
         WHEN nv < 0 THEN TCCIN
         ELSE nv 
       END AS Delta 
FROM   (SELECT *, 
               TCCIN - (SELECT  TCCIN
                       FROM   corona t1 
                       WHERE  t1.id < t2.id 
                              AND t1.NameofState = t2.NameofState
                       ORDER  BY id DESC
                       limit 1)nv 
        FROM   corona t2) t
```

```
 (SELECT TCCIN FROM corona WHERE NameofState=NameofState and Date = SUBDATE(Date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) FROM corona
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: what else you want in this situation

Comment: I suppose I want Stack Overflow to be a better environment for us all.

Comment: I mean what else you want me to add here to make my Question answerable

Comment: You're very close, just need to take the date into consierdation in your sub query

Comment: I'm not sure why this is thumbed down.. He provided an example and his question was clear. He even provided his attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I have posted this answer once and it was deleted by a mod presumably because it only had a short sentence and a link. I have made modifications to the answer, but it remains deleted. If my original post is undeleted, I will delete this one.

This is the answer, it had already been accepted by OP:

You just need to take the date into consideration in your sub query. You were really close, have a look at the sql fiddle I've set up with your example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ee775/2/0

Edit: Post got deleted, so adding more details.

In op's post he didn't order the sub query by date, all that was needed was an extra order by and a condition that would pick the largest date.

Here is the modified query that works:

```
SELECT *, 
    (
        SELECT TCCIN
        FROM corona t1
        WHERE t1.id < t2.id 
        AND t1.NameofState=t2.NameofState
        AND t1.Date < t2.DateTime #get max date
        ORDER BY Date desc
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS prevDate
FROM corona t2
```